# Use counter in global text

Tags: macros, counters

I would like to set a variable or command \i available anywhere in the document, so that it changes every time it appears in the text in the same way as a counter.

For example text:

This is value \i and now it is value \i

Would produce

This is value 1 and now it is value 2

I am slightly familiar with counters but I cannot manage to modify them so that I get the desired result. I do not really know how to handle the context so that they do not modify the text in any way and can be used everywhere (Tables in different sections mostly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a counter and create a command that shows the value of the counter and adds one to it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{counti}
\setcounter{counti}{1}% <--- Initial value
\newcommand{\ci}{%
\thecounti% <--- Show value
\stepcounter{counti}% < --- Add 1
}

\begin{document}

Hello \ci\ world \ci. This \ci\ is \ci\ a \ci\ test \ci.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{icount}
\newcommand{\hi}{\stepcounter{icount}\theicount}
\begin{document}
This is value \hi\ and now it is value \hi.
\end{document}
```